# How to work Facebook 'Like' button

Tags: javascript, security

From My technical interests.
I'd like to how to work Facebook 'Like' button?

are there any security risk?

for example:

-Someone push my like button.

--if I 'm stolen my cookies
If there is a blog that detailed explanation
Could I have the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is always a security risk involved in letting in Javascript from other domains (from the viewpoint of the user and third-party site provider), although that risk is somewhat minized if you serve your button inside an `<iframe>` on a separate *API*-like subdomain. That prevents parent Javascript code access to the contents of the frame and vice-versa. Basically, from the inside of the `<iframe>` you can only access the URL property of the parent page (and some other minor parameters).

Comment: Thank you for replying . but is it not https ? if my cookies are stolen someone can put my like button? or Does FB have any protection?

Comment: Cookies can be read inside the browser only if the Javascript originated from the same domain (same-domain security policy, the same reason you can't do cross-domain AJAX), so no, other people can't read your cookies if the code comes from another domain. Also, anyone can read your cookies if you're using unencrypted wifi without SSL – see [Firesheep](http://codebutler.github.com/firesheep/).

Comment: OK I got it! summarize　the circumstance non ssl with facebook like button has risk that read and write someone my like request , thank you so much

Comment: Just to clarify: using Facebook's like button by including it via http:// and not https:// will present a risk for users on public wifi.